# Using Jackson Json to parse Google Blogs post

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have been struggling to parse this feed using jackson Json Parser.

Here is the feed:

```
    {
"responseData": {
"query": "Official Google Blogs",
"entries": [
{
"url": "http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default",
"title": "<b>Official Blog</b>",
"contentSnippet": "5 days ago <b>...</b> <b>Official</b> weblog, with news of new products, events and glimpses of life inside <br>  <b>Google</b>.",
"link": "http://googleblog.blogspot.com/"
},
{
"url": "http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default",
"title": "<b>Official Google</b> Webmaster Central <b>Blog</b>",
"contentSnippet": "Jul 12, 2013 <b>...</b> The <b>official</b> weblog on <b>Google</b> crawling and indexing, and on webmaster tools, <br>  including the Sitemaps facility.",
"link": "http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/"
},

{
"url": "http://googlemac.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default",
"title": "<b>Official Google</b> Mac <b>Blog</b>",
"contentSnippet": "Jun 22, 2012 <b>...</b> The <b>official</b> weblog about <b>Google</b> in the Apple Macintosh world.",
"link": "http://googlemac.blogspot.com/"
}
]
},
"responseDetails": null,
"responseStatus": 200
}
```

I have managed to get all the objects except the "entries" array de-serialized.

Any Idea?

Here is the code for my data model:

```
public class UserModel {

public static final String TAG = UserModel.class.getSimpleName()


public static class ResponseData{
    private String _query;
    public String getQuery(){return _query;}
    public void setQuery(String query){_query=query;}
    // I am unable to get the entries parsing


}



private String responseStatus;
private String responseDetails; 
private ResponseData responseData;


public ResponseData getresponseData() {
    return responseData;
}



public void setresponseData(ResponseData responseData) {
       this.responseData = responseData;
   }


    public String getresponseStatus() {
        return responseStatus;
    }

    public void setresponseStatus(String responseStatus) {
        this.responseStatus = responseStatus;
    }
    public String getresponseDetails() {
        return responseDetails;
    }

    public void setresponseDetails(String responseDetails) {
        this.responseDetails = responseDetails;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("ResponseStatus [ResponseStatus=");
        builder.append(responseStatus);
        builder.append(responseData._query);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the list of entries as a List type to your responseData class and also create a class that represents the Entry class (called entry in the below example, but call it whatever you want).

```
public static class ResponseData{

     public List<Entry> entries;
     private String _query;
     public String getQuery(){return _query;}
     public void setQuery(String query){_query=query;}
     // I am unable to get the entries parsing


}
```

EDIT:
Also - make sure your Entry class contains the properties from the JSON response. It should have a url, title, contentSnippet, and link property.

Comment: Hi- thats great. Once I have added the list type how do I then populate them using Getters and setters like the others?

Comment: Well if you leave it public, jackson will automatically populate the objects entries. In fact, in android is not uncommon to just use public members for model objects (as getters and setters are considered more expensive - although, that recommendation from google was made a long time ago...). If you want it to follow the same way as the other members, then just make it private and add a getter and setter (getEntries, setEntries respectively) - Jackson should still pick this property up and set it based on the JSON.

Comment: @androidbloke any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understand your problem.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(query);
JSONObject responseData = data.getJSONObject("responseData");
JSONArray entries = responseData.getJSONArray("entries");
List<JSONObject> pEntries = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for(int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++){
   pEntries.add(entries.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

For taking String from JSONObject call getString("name");

Comment: Hi I am after doing this using the Jackson Library